# RxSwift : BehaviorRelay in place of Variable usage

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, rx-swift

I'm new to RxSwift and reading about subjects, I tried `Variable` Subject. Which in turns giving Warning in console

```
ℹ️ [DEPRECATED] `Variable` is planned for future deprecation. Please consider `BehaviorRelay` as a replacement. Read more at: https://git.io/vNqvx
```

Earlier I have declared `Variable` like this

```
var searchItems = Variable<[MyClass]>([])
```

So i have done basic array operations from it's property called `value` as it was `get set` property like

```
 1. self.searchItems.value.removeAll()
 2. self.searchItems.value.append(items)
 3. self.searchItems.value = items
```

Now After getting warning i changed it to `BehaviorRelay` like

```
var searchItems = BehaviorRelay<[MyClass]>(value: [])
```

So I got error that **value is get property only**.

I googled alot but can't get suitable explanations for Array operations.

I only got a code `self.searchItems.accept(items)` which i really don't know what it exactly do add fresh items or append.

I needed how all 4 operations will be performed when using `BehaviorRelay`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1) Remove all**

```
var array = self.searchItems.value
array.removeAll()
self.searchItems.accept(array)
```

**2) Append item**

```
self.searchItems.value.accept(searchItems + [items])
```

**3) Value = ...**

```
self.searchItems.value.accept(items)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `accept`.

```
var value = searchItems.value
value.removeAll()
searchItems.accept(value)
```

etc...

Comment: This answer was prior to maxwell's - TBH It would've been more fair to accept :) Anyways both are correct.